# How to load a different header.php depending on Multilanguage plugin's selected language?

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I am currently testing my WordPress site on localhost. I have managed to use Multilanguage plugin to change all of pages' content. But since my main content is in the editor and my menu is in header.php I am unable to do the same for my menu. Which raises a question - how to load a different header.php, translated to another language, depending on the selected language? Or is it better to have my menu included in the editor as well, so I can change it the same way I change my main content? Wouldn't that be inefficient since all of my pages use the same header?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which Multilanguage plugin do you use?

Comment: @pgk it's called Multilanguage by BestWebSoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `Multilanguage by BestWebSoft` plugin, you must check the documentation for some plugin-released method for changing your header. But if you want to do this switch manualy, you can do something like this:

Because `get_header()` can load diferent header templates, you can create several header files, named `header.php`, `header-fr.php`, `header-de.php` etc. In these files you can do what you want for current language. Then you must load proper header:

```
//get gurrent language
global $mltlngg_current_language; //this contains current locale in format 'en_EN' ...

get_header(explode('_', $mltlngg_current_language)[0]);
```

So if your current lang is `fr_FR`, `get_header('fr')` will search for `header-fr.php` file, and if missing, will load default `header.php` file.

Of course, if the difference between header files is only language specific, you can use WP built-in functions for translation [L10n functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/L10n). and create your own translation.

Again, this is manual way to do this job, maybe your plugin can provide better way to do this :)

P.S: You can search plugin documentation to find better way to grab current language locale.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Worked like a charm.

Comment: For those who have the plugin installed, it is not necessary to declare $mltlngg_current_language as global in your template file as it is already declared so in multilanguage.php. Essentially, just create additional manually translated headers and use the get_header as mentioned above by pgk